# Basic Memory Match Game in Java

Tags: java, game

I'm relatively new to Java and decided to make a Memory Match game.

**Card.java:**

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Card extends JButton{
    private int id;
    private boolean matched = false;


    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }


    public void setMatched(boolean matched){
        this.matched = matched;
    }

    public boolean getMatched(){
        return this.matched;
    }
}
```

**Board.java:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Board extends JFrame{


    private List<Card> cards;
    private Card selectedCard;
    private Card c1;
    private Card c2;
    private Timer t;

    public Board(){

        int pairs = 10;
        List<Card> cardsList = new ArrayList<Card>();
        List<Integer> cardVals = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pairs; i++){
            cardVals.add(i);
            cardVals.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cardVals);

        for (int val : cardVals){
            Card c = new Card();
            c.setId(val);
            c.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    selectedCard = c;
                    doTurn();
                }
            });
            cardsList.add(c);
        }
        this.cards = cardsList;
        //set up the timer
        t = new Timer(750, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                checkCards();
            }
        });

        t.setRepeats(false);

        //set up the board itself
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 5));
        for (Card c : cards){
            pane.add(c);
        }
        setTitle("Memory Match");
    }

    public void doTurn(){
        if (c1 == null && c2 == null){
            c1 = selectedCard;
            c1.setText(String.valueOf(c1.getId()));
        }

        if (c1 != null && c1 != selectedCard && c2 == null){
            c2 = selectedCard;
            c2.setText(String.valueOf(c2.getId()));
            t.start();

        }
    }

    public void checkCards(){
        if (c1.getId() == c2.getId()){//match condition
            c1.setEnabled(false); //disables the button
            c2.setEnabled(false);
            c1.setMatched(true); //flags the button as having been matched
            c2.setMatched(true);
            if (this.isGameWon()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You win!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        else{
            c1.setText(""); //'hides' text
            c2.setText("");
        }
        c1 = null; //reset c1 and c2
        c2 = null;
    }

    public boolean isGameWon(){
        for(Card c: this.cards){
            if (c.getMatched() == false){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Game.java:**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Game{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Board b = new Board();
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500)); //need to use this instead of setSize
        b.setLocation(500, 250);
        b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b.pack();
        b.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

The code compiles and the game works, which is fine, but how could I improve, if at all, from a stylistic perspective? If it helps, before Java I worked in primarily Python and C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Card class

Your `id` does not change after being set once. This makes it perfect for being set inside a constructor. This will also allow you to make it `private final int id;` . It is a good practice to use `final` fields whenever possible.

Instead of:

```
Card c = new Card();
c.setId(val);
```

Do:

```
Card c = new Card(val);
```

#### Board

`selectedCard` is only a temporarily-used variable which is set in one method and read directly afterwards in another. It should be passed on to the `doTurn` method, no need to use it as a class field.

Instead of:

```
selectedCard = c;
doTurn();
```

Do:

```
doTurn(c);
```

#### doTurn

As suggested above, this method should take the `selectedCard` parameter directly.

At the moment, this method does a little bit too much and contains some slight code duplication.

```
c1.setText(String.valueOf(c1.getId()));
c2.setText(String.valueOf(c2.getId()));
```

There's no fundamental difference between those two lines, and if asked what those lines do you would probably say something like "it shows the text on the cards". Now let's make that a method in the `Card` class!

```
 public void showText() {
      this.setText(String.valueOf(id));
 }
```

Your `doTurn` method then becomes:

```
public void doTurn(Card selectedCard) {
    if (c1 == null && c2 == null) {
        c1 = selectedCard;
        c1.showText();
    }
    else if (c1 != null && c1 != selectedCard && c2 == null) {
        c2 = selectedCard;
        c2.showText();
        t.start();
    }
}
```

#### checkCards

```
if (c1.getId() == c2.getId()){//match condition
```

Can be extracted to a method and called like:

```
if (c1.hasSameId(c2)) {
```

---

```
c1.setEnabled(false); //disables the button
c2.setEnabled(false);
c1.setMatched(true); //flags the button as having been matched
c2.setMatched(true);
```

Code duplication. Can be extracted to `c1.matchButton();`

---

```
System.exit(0);
```

This is an 'evil' way of exiting your application. It is preferred to close the `JFrame` instead and shut down the timer. That will exit your application in a more 'friendly' way.

---

```
c1.setText(""); //'hides' text
c2.setText("");
```

Again, method extraction will make this code more self-explanatory, and make the buttons better be responsible for what they should be responsible for.

```
c1.hideText();
c2.hideText();
```

#### Game Won and Streams

In Java 8 (which I believe that you are using) your `isGameWon` method can be simplified:

```
public boolean isGameWon(){
    return this.cards.stream().allMatch(c -> c.isMatched());
}
```

#### Composition over inheritance

This goes back to the `Card` class primarily:

```
public class Card extends JButton
```

With the above suggestions of extracting methods to make the `Card` class be responsible for setting text and disabling the buttons and stuff, you can remove the `extends JButton` and write it more like this:

```
public class Card {
     private final int id;
     private final Button button = new Button();
     ...

     public Card(int id) {
          this.id = id;
     }

     public Button getButton() {
          return this.button;
     }

     ...
}
```

And create it like this:

```
Card c = new Card(val);
c.setId(val);
c.getButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        selectedCard = c;
        doTurn();
    }
});
```

#### The extra step

This is a slightly more advanced concept. Use it at your own risk, if you feel that you can understand it.

Side note: It is possible to make this even better, by for example pass on a `Consumer<Card>` to the `Card` class and pass on `this::doTurn` when constructing the cards, and have your `Card` action listener call this `Consumer<Card>`.

On the positive side, this will remove the need of exposing the `Button` in your `Card` class. On the negative side, this might be a bit "over your head" at the moment.

```
Card c = new Card(val, this::doTurn);


public class Card {
     private final int id;
     private final Button button = new Button();
     ...

     public Card(int id, Consumer<Card> onClick) {
          this.id = id;
          this.button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                  onClick.accept(Card.this);
              }
          });
     }

     public Button getButton() {
          return this.button;
     }

     ...
}
```